# include path and the __autoload function in php

Tags: php, autoload, include-path

I am trying to convert several php scripts to use the __autoload function.  Right now I can use the include and require functions like this:

```
require_once('path/to/script.php');
```

But inside of the __autoload function, I can't use the line above.  I have to use this:

```
require_once('absolute/path/to/script.php');
```

Why does it seem as though the __autoload function doesn't use the include path I have specified in php.ini?

Comment: Technically this isn't an answer to your question but you might find it helpful so I'll put this as a comment: Since all of your includes are now going through autoload, why bother with the php.ini include path at all? You can just define the include folder relative to the file which contains the autoload function. For example, if the file is at root and includes are at /include/ then just prepend 'include/' inside of autoload.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `echo get_include_path();`? The only case I can think of there this may happen is when `.` is not in your include path.

Comment: @nikic: It's there I check using that echo statement, as well as, looking at the php.ini file itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `__autoload`...  It has a few drawbacks (including limiting yourself to one per execution).  Use instead [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register) if you're on 5.2+.

So what I typically do, is have a class:

```
class AutoLoader {
    protected static $paths = array(
        PATH_TO_LIBRARIES,
    );
    public static function addPath($path) {
        $path = realpath($path);
        if ($path) {
            self::$paths[] = $path;
        }
    }
    public static function load($class) {
        $classPath = $class; // Do whatever logic here
        foreach (self::$paths as $path) {
            if (is_file($path . $classPath)) {
                require_once $path . $classPath;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register(array('AutoLoader', 'load'));
```

That way, if you add a library set, you can just "add it" to your paths by calling `AutoLoader::AddPath($path);`.  This makes testing with your autoloader a LOT easier (IMHO).

One other note.  Don't throw exceptions from the autoload class unless absolutely necessary.  The reason is that you can install multiple autoloaders, so if you don't know how to load the file, another one may exist to load it.  But if you throw an exception, it'll skip the other one...

Personally, I don't ever like to use relative paths with includes.  Especially with multiple include directories (like pear), it makes it very difficult to know exactly which file is being imported when you see `require 'foo/bar.php';`.  I prefer to define the absolute path in the beginning of the file set `define('PATH_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));`, and then define all my other useful paths off of that directory (`PATH_LIBRARIES`, `PATH_TEMPLATES`, etc...).  That way, everything is absolutely defined...  And no need to deal with relative paths (like the issue you're having now)...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing the whole set-up. My autoload function is within my global functions file, and looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (file_exists("includes/{$class}.php")) {
        require_once("includes/{$class}.php");
    }
    /**
     * Add any additional directories to search in within an else if statement here
     */
    else {
        // handle error gracefully
    }
}
```

I use a relative path because the script is included in my `index.php` file and all HTTP requests are passed through it.

Comment: It seems like part of your answer was cut off for some reason. The part after "because" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `__autoload()` function is in a separate file then the code which calls it. The path to the included files will be relative to the file which the `__autoload()` function declaration resides.

Comment: I thought that too, but then I used the setting in the php.ini file called "auto_prepend_file" and the file that contained the __autoload function in the folder where all the relative paths begin and it still wouldn't work.

Comment: -1 because I think this answer is wrong (correct me, if it is I, who is wrong): As far as I know the file is included relative to the exeucted script. That is, if an index.php is called, but the autoload resides in foo/bar/autoload.php, still the path would be resolved relative to index.php. PHP will only fall back to foo/bar as the very last step, after trying all include_paths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `.` is not in your include path. So add it use:

```
set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Now PHP should look relative to the executed scripts directory, too. (Executed script here is something like `index.php`, not `autoload.php`.

But why don't use simply use a normal relative path like `./path/to/class.php`?

Comment: `.` is in the path already.  `.` is relative to the current working directory of the current file (in other words, it's equivalant to `dirname(__FILE__)`)...   That's why it works fine from one file but not the other (because the relative working directory changes between them)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: And you are **really** sure, that what you say is right? I had the experience, that PHP regards the directory as cwd, there the *originally* executed script lies, not there the file you include from lies. [More information (though German)](https://www.lima-city.de/thread/inclusion-path-resolution) and my [Path resolution class](http://github.com/nikic/prephp/blob/master/prephp/classes/Path.php). (The resolution class isn't yet perfect, though.)